# Where to Install OWASP Benchmark?

Tags: maven, benchmarking, owasp, penetration-testing

I am trying to scan the OWASP Benchmark with ZAP. However, I am having trouble getting the Owasp benchmark up and running. I have installed maven and the jdk required. I have ran the ./runBenchmark.sh script and everything is processed properly and I get the container is running screen. However, when I try to open it in browser, only the default Apache page is displayed.
Is it because I cloned the Benchmark in documents folder rather than var/www/html ?
Please help

Comment: This question has nothing to do with zap. I'd suggest an edit removing the tag but supposedly the suggested edits queue on SO is full.

Comment: Welcome to SO Aditya Kolte. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Based on your description, it is difficult to guess what might be going on.